# How could I change boost release variant to use cxxflags=-O2?

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam

On my machine cxxflags for variant=release is -O3 by default.
I need to change it to -O2.
Please advise how to proceed.

I am fine with defining a new variant as well, if someone could advise me on that.

Comment: try
bjam release -n -a
to know for sure if it is -O3 or -O2 now

Comment: Thanks usta.
Used "bjam release -n -a" .
shows
"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall  -DNDEBUG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
<variant>release:<cxxflags>-O2
```

as requirements on top-level project. Options specified with cxxflags are passed to gcc after all the other options, so -O3 will be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to create a new variant, like this:

```
    variant o2release : <cxxflags>-O2 <debug-symbols>off <inlining>full <runtime-debugging>off define=NDEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks. I had access to the feature.jam file and I was able to change O3 to O2 for optimization in gcc. That worked as well.

Comment: Yep, that's also an option when local modification is OK for you :)